# How to stop the IDE window from maximizing when running an application within Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2010

I noticed that if I set the Delphi 2010 IDE window to be something other than maximized it automatically maximizes when I run an application friom inside the IDE. When the program is closed, the IDE window resizes back to the size it was prior to running the program.

Is there anyway to turn off this annoying behavior?

Comment: This problem (and solution) appear to apply to Delphi XE4 as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because you have defined a Debug Desktop. You can either switch off the Debug Desktop feature, or define a different desktop view to be your Debug Desktop.

The settings are under the View | Desktops menu if I recall correctly.

I find this feature very powerful, especially combined with my multiple monitors. The debug desktop lives on a separate monitor so it doesn't overlap with my app window. And I can also configure the layout of call stack, watches, locals windows that I don't show in my standard desktop.

Comment: Thank you, works like a champ. View|Desktops|Set Debug Desktop... [set to none]. I sure am taking a lot more from SO than I'm giving.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - finding a way of turning off this gratuitous nonsense put an end to a constant annoyance (since some harebrain decided it might be fun to have the desktops maximise themselves on every switch, regardless of their former state). Start  debugging, restore IDE from maximised state to something workable, do stuff, stop debugging, restore IDE from maximised state to something workable, ..., ad infinitum.

Comment: P.S.: the disruption can be further minimised by disabling 'Hide designers on run' under Tools / Options / Environment Options and/or switching the default desktop to the debug desktop.

Comment: To be noted that if a debug desktop is defined, Delphi will SOMETIMES jump to a random monitor to random IDE window size.